# can't console log the div I click on

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a connect four game and right now I just want the console log the div that's being clicked on the board. But for some reason the div that's being logged isn't the one that's clicked on.The div that's logged is always at the bottom of the board? Can someone please help me understand why this is happening. Thanks:)

```js
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".slot");

for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
 board[i].addEventListener('click', dropChip);
}

function dropChip() {
 console.log(this);
}
```

```css
/** {
 border: 1px solid red;
}*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e6e9ef;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.board-wrapper {
  /*display: flex;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #00c;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 706px;
  padding: 3px;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}

.board>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid #00c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.board>div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -999em;
  bottom: -999em;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.board>div:hover:after {
  background-color: #00c;
}

.board>div.counter {
  /*display: block;
 padding: 0;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e6e9ef;
  z-index: 100;
}

.board>div.counter:after {
  /*content: "";*/
  /*display: block;*/
  /*padding: 0;*/
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  /*left: 0;
 right: auto;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform .5s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  /*transform: translateX(0);*/
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
}

.board>div.counter:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px #cc0000;
  z-index: 101;
  transition: transform .5s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  /*transform: translateX(0);*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(14px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(114px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(214px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(314px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(414px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(514px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(614px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(14px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(114px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(214px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(314px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(414px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(514px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(614px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Connect Four</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="board-wrapper">
    <div class="board">
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="counter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add onclick event handler passing the event

Comment: Don't add an event listener to each div, instead add one event listener to the '.board' div and use event.target to find out which div generated that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting out `.board>div:after` CSS rule solves the problem of the right `this` context. It's because all your slot `div`s are the same height. So the lower most `div`s in the DOM are positioned above the rest. Your JS is actually fine, it's the CSS that makes the `div`s so large that it looks like you're clicking on one, but the click is registered on something else much lower in the DOM.

```js
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".slot");

for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
 board[i].addEventListener('click', dropChip);
}

function dropChip() {
 console.log(this);
}
```

```css
/** {
 border: 1px solid red;
}*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e6e9ef;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.board-wrapper {
  /*display: flex;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #00c;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 706px;
  padding: 3px;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}

.board>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid #00c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

/* Commented out.
.board>div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -999em;
  bottom: -999em;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  background-color: transparent;
}*/

.board>div:hover:after {
  background-color: #00c;
}

.board>div.counter {
  /*display: block;
 padding: 0;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e6e9ef;
  z-index: 100;
}

.board>div.counter:after {
  /*content: "";*/
  /*display: block;*/
  /*padding: 0;*/
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  /*left: 0;
 right: auto;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform .5s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  /*transform: translateX(0);*/
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
}

.board>div.counter:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px #cc0000;
  z-index: 101;
  transition: transform .5s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  /*transform: translateX(0);*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(14px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(114px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(214px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(314px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(414px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(514px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.counter:after {
  transform: translateX(614px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(14px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(114px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(214px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(314px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(414px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(514px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.board>div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover~.counter:before {
  transform: translateX(614px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Connect Four</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="board-wrapper">
    <div class="board">
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="slot"></div>
      <div class="counter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If the purpose of that rule is to highlight all the `div`s in a column, you might need a different approach.

Comment: So are you saying since each div.slot is being stretched with the :after pseudo element that if I click on a div.slot in the top row I'm really clicking on the bottom one because its stretched to the top? I'm new to programming and someone off sitepoint made this for me lol

Comment: Yup. You can inspect the DOM and see the height of each of the `div.slot`

Answer (score 4):

It's been found out that the issue is actually the CSS, but I'm leaving this here for extra infomation.

The common approach would be to pass the `event.target` as an argument on the `dropChip` function

```
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".slot");

for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt){ dropChip(evt.target) });
}


function dropChip(div) {
    console.log(div);
}
```

Event listeners will always automatically supply an `event` object when executing the callback, which is why we added an `evt` parameter on our anonymous function.

You can also omit the anonymous function if you want to be straightforward

```
for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i].addEventListener('click', dropChip);
}


function dropChip(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target);
}
```

You can also pass the iterated item instead during the loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt){ dropChip(board[i]) });
}
```

Comment: If the last point is true, could you explain why `this` in anonymous fn as event listener behaves normal? While one in named fn (like OP did) doesn't? I'm so confused why OP's code doesn't work, seem valid to me.

Comment: @hackape I do not use that approach anymore, but I was sure it would work. Tested it right now on OP's code and it actually doesn't. I'll just remove it to avoid confusion

Comment: @hackape the `this` approach is not really normal, and most of us wouldn't even remember/know that it is a viable technique as it is confusing. I actually removed OP's CSS and used `this`, and now it works, even OP's own code. Sounds like we have a different situation here.

Comment: Wat? You mean it's actually a css problem?

Comment: @hackape I think so. I added a number as a text content on the markup so I can see what divs are being logged upon clicking, and then removed the css. It works lol. But hey, I could be wrong, i'm just stealthily leisure browsing SO at work so I'm not very sure

Comment: Lol this is such a curious case, I need to see it myself.

Comment: @hackape Go ahead, once you confirm this and edit your answer, I might delete mine (or clarify that the issue is css) since the issue is not the script.

Comment: No pls don't, let other people see the process of discovery, including this conversation. This is how things actually happen, not just the answer matters.

Comment: This didn't work? It still isn't logging the div I clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I don't use `this` in event listener. I find it very confusing, should be considered an antipattern. You can use `evt.target`, way more clear.

```
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".slot");

for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i].addEventListener('click', dropChip);
}

function dropChip(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target);
}
```

As to an explanation, I'm confused too. I think your code should work...

---

**Edit**: So it turns out to be a css problem (see Maaz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682475/3617380)), I didn't look into the stylesheet, miss that part. OP's script is valid, it does work.

Comment: This didn't work? It still isn't logging the div I clicked on?